# Built in keyboard won't work - Acer Chromebook R11 Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, keyboard, chromebook

I'm trying to run Ubuntu 16.10 on a flash drive (not Crouton) on an Acer Chromebook R11. The built in keyboard won't work, but a USB keyboard does. I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, that didn't change anything.

Any log files I could check to see what's happening? Is it possible to fix this?

Output of `lsusb` and `xinput`:

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b490 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


xinput

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Could you list the output of `lsusb` and `xinput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After skimming [this discussion](https://github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-distro/issues/270#issuecomment-263014919), it is my understanding that the keyboard works with linux kernel 4.7 but not 4.8.

I am now using the latest GalliumOS baytrail nightly and the keyboard works fine.